# Finding correlation between two percentages

Tags: regression, correlation

I have lots of graphs that look similar to this one:

[image]

I want to find the 5 graphs where the correlation between the green and blue bars is the greatest.

I want to measure the correlation between the green and the blue bars on this graph, if there is one. The green bars sum to 100% and the blue bars also sum to 100%.

I had thought of measuring the difference between each pair of blue and green bars, summing it and squaring it. I don't remember much from my statistics class but I think this is called linear regression (please correct me if I'm wrong).

I was going to do this for all of my graphs and pick the 5 where R squared is the smallest. Is this correct and if not, what method should I use instead?

Thanks,
Francis

**EDIT:**
Thanks to everyone who's helped so far. I think my original question was worded incorrectly. When I said I wanted to find the correlation between the green and blue bars, I meant I want to find the correlation between the `counters` and `time` variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "correlation between green and blue bars"?  Bars in a histogram don't have correlations between them. You can pick which are most similar or most different. Correlations are between variables.

Comment: @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica Thanks for your help, I think I just worded my question incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample correlation is measured for a dataset containing a *set* of pairs of variables, and it requires at least two pairs of variables to be well-defined (each pair is essentially a single datapoint, and we need at least two of these).  Thus, it is possible to compute the sample correlation between `counters` and `time` for the entire dataset you have shown, but it is not possible to compute correlation for a single pair of values.  You could pick the point where both values make the greatest *contribution* to the sample correlation for the overall data-set, but I do not see what that accomplishes.

I'm afraid that this appears to be one of the "false premise" questions we get a bit on this site, where the questioner is asking of advice on how to implement a procedure that either does not exist, or does not constitute a good method of analysis to begin with.  Rather than asking how you might implement some arbitrarily constructed procedure, it would be more useful if you were to ask a new question explaining the overall research/statistical question you have for this data, and seeking advice on how best to deal with this.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the detail in your answer was very helpful.